# Why custom templatetags in django-basic-apps use get_model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Why the custom templatetags get the model using get_model in django-basic-apps instead of importing directly? Is there any specific technical reason for this?

For ex: in https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps/blob/master/basic/groups/templatetags/groups.py

```
GroupMember = models.get_model('groups', 'groupmember')
```

Note: The views in all the django-basic-apps import the models directly
https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps/blob/master/basic/groups/views/groups.py

```
from basic.groups.models import *
```

Comment: My guess would be so as not to throw an `ImportError`

Comment: `models.get_model()` returns `None` instead of throwing an `ImportError` so what Tim said.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Kindly request you to answer this for now so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`models.get_model` won't throw an `ImportError` if the model doesn't exist